# Mongo query $lte with $match not working

Tags: mongodb-query

```
db.users.aggregate([{

$addFields: {
    age: { $subtract: [57, 20] },
    age2: { $subtract: [67, 20] }
  }
},
{ $project: { age: 1, age2: 1 } },
{
  $match: {
      age: { $lte: "$age" }
  }
}
])
```

This code is not working, replace "$age" with any number or float the it works.

Please can anyone explain this behaviour?

Mongo shell version 3.4

Comment: what is `age: { $lte: "$age" }` ???

Comment: any variable with value equals to 37, and age 2 with value 47

Comment: post your collection and sample output

Comment: this query is good for any db. Just run this query for the first time and for the second time replace $age with 37 in $match pipeline. you will get a clear picture of my question.

Comment: this doesn't seems to be working at all